# Java String.split() and compare

Tags: java, html, string, split, flying-saucer

Im working with flying saucer and want to export an xhtml to an pdf. 
Everything works fine, but now I want to add an empty column, for example for descriptions or something.

I want to create a method addColumn(). which should add in every row of the table at the end a new, empty cell.

I tried following code:

```
            String[] arr = content.split("<td");
            String test = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if(i != 0){
                arr[i] = "<td" + arr[i];
                test += arr[i];
                }
            }
```

This should split the content on every beginning `"td"` tag. 
`String.split("<td")` removes the `"<td"` from the content so i want to add it again.

But if i compare those:

```
if(test.equalsIgnoreCase(content)){
     System.out.println("SUCCESS");
}
else{
     System.out.println("FAIL");
}
```

I always fail.

Just help me to get the right content back out of the array, this would make me go a step in the right direction!

Thank you.

Comment: please post input string, actual output and expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your `split` line with this:

```
String[] arr = content.split("<td", -1);
```

Otherwise you will loose some input in `arr`, see [the `split(String)` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

The added `-1` makes sure that your `content` can also contain `"<tr"` at its beginning, for example. See [the `split(String, int)` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for further explanations.